# What's the best way to display summary statistics for categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, descriptive-statistics

I collected data that includes factor variables, like employment status and even age (collected as "between 20 and 30", etc.).

I know how to make summary statistics table in R or Stata, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to display the table with categorical variables, since min max and median are all meaningless for the categorical ones.

What would be the best way then to display the descriptive statistics when there are both categorical and continuous variables in the data set?

Comment: Have you looked at data published in a journal in your field? In medical journals, for example, categorical data is often presented with 1 row per category where the cell entries are "N (percentage)"; for binary categories, it is common to present only one, like "Women 1342 (40)" to indicate a sample was 40% women - what is "best," on the other hand, is going to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Related:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32813/what-summary-statistics-to-use-with-categorical-or-qualitative-variables?rq=1