# Vaccination acceptance by subregion and country of residence visualization name and instrument to build the similar one

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, survey

I've found a pretty interesting visualization in the article "High monkeypox vaccine acceptance among male users of smartphone-based online gay-dating apps in Europe, 30 July to 12 August 2022" ([link](https://www.eurosurveillance.org/content/10.2807/1560-7917.ES.2022.27.42.2200757#f2)) with visualized data according vaccination acceptance among survey participants by country, subregion and with calculated 90% CI for each country and subregion.

Does anyone know the name of this chart and instruments to build the similar one?[image]

Comment: It looks like a typical dot chart, except it shows uncertainties/confidence intervals as well which is perhaps not standard. Dot charts can be made with most statistical software. Am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: @mkt I think you are right. I've tried to interpret this chart as one, however, after your comment I took another point of view and now this graph looks just like bubble plot with overplotted CI on it, thus, as two graphs on one. Ty

Answer (score 2):

The terminology for basic plots like this is not entirely standardised, but I would say this is a fairly typical [dot chart (or Cleveland dot chart)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/149146/121522). It does, however, have a couple of features that are not seen in the prototypical dot chart:

1. It shows uncertainties/confidence intervals.
2. It uses size, colour, and shape to convey some additional pieces of information.

Point #2 may lead you to call this a bubble plot but I don't think that would be accurate. Bubble plots usually refer to a scatterplot that shows variation in a third dimension using variation in point size.