# Are pie charts evil?

Tags: pie-chart

Are pie charts, at least the 2d versions, the best choice in some cases?

Or, should they be simply taboo for any serious objective data visualization?

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8974/1036. If the answers to that question are not sufficient, I think you need to be clearer about what you are looking for in an answer. Evil implies a malicious intent -- so is more about the chart maker than the chart. (You could maybe swap out "evil" with "harmful" though and still have the same gist.)

Comment: Only in D&D 3.5e and 4e. In D&D 5e, they were changed to chaotic neutral.

Comment: @Sycorax upvote!